# Finding the vertices of a rectangle

Tags: c#, winforms

Trying to find the vertices of rectangle. I found the the first vertex and stored it in variable x1,y1, but when I try to find the the 2nd vertex x2, I'm unable to find it.

Code so far is

```
private void process(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Image);
  int set = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < bmp.Height; i++)
  {
    for (int j = 0; j < bmp.Width; j++)
    {
      Color p = bmp.GetPixel(j, i);
      if (set < bmp.Width && p.R < 10)
      {
        x1 = j;
        y1 = i;
        for (k = x1; k < bmp.Width; k++)
        {
          set++;
          if (bmp.GetPixel(k, i).R < 10 || bmp.GetPixel(k + 1, i).R > 200)
          {
            x2 = k;
            bmp.SetPixel(k, i, Color.Red);
            break;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  } 
  pictureBox1.Image = bmp;
  MessageBox.Show("(" + x2 + ")");
} //end class process.
```

Comment: You need to clarify __exactly__  __all__ you know about your problem. And you should tell us! Putting __comments__ in your code will help everybody, first of all it will help you. So I assume you have a bitmap with a rectangle drawn on it? Do you know if the rectangle can be tilted? How thick are the strokes? Is it filled? What colors do you expect? Will there be anti-aliasing/smoothing? For an untitlted rectangle I would search for one point (any point) and go from there until I have found a point on each side and deduce the corners from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Your code finds x2 allright**. Well, almost. Your condition in the innermost loops should be **and** (`&&`) not **or** (`||`).  The second mistake somewhat makes good for the first, but that's not the way to go..

The second mistake is that you don't `break` out of your inner loop correctly.

Note: in C# a `break` command only breaks out of the **innermost** loop.

(Which is the k-loop; which incidently is an undefinend variable?)

If you want to break out further go need to do it in some other way. The discussion how to do it best is old and quite emotional. Some suggest to set the loop conditions of the next loops to false, others advise the use of `goto`, which was included in C# for just that situation. (And one or two more..)

I think this is a case where a `goto` is the cleanest and most simple solution as is says what it does without tweaking loop variable or introducing more variables..

So here is the portion of your code to change:

```
       if (bmp.GetPixel(k, i).R < 10  && bmp.GetPixel(k + 1, i).R > 200)
       {
         x2 = k;
         bmp.SetPixel(k, i, Color.Red);
         goto loop1;
       }
     }
   }
 }

}
loop1:
pictureBox1.Image = bmp;
MessageBox.Show("(" + x2 + ")")
```